# Java: proper way to get the class of a primitive array for reflection

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, primitive

I'm trying to use reflection to call a method that takes in a byte array.

I'm starting off doing:

```
Class myClass = anObject.getClass();
Class[] parameterTypes =
 {byte[].getClass();};
```

But that doesn't work (class expected, } expected) on the byte[] line.  Anyone know what I should do?  Cast to an Object and declare that the method takes an Object?

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[] {byte[].class};
```

Comment: great, thanks, that worked.  I don't really understand why 
Integer[] x = {5}; and Integer[] y = {new Integer(5)}; work.

Comment: Well, `Class[] parameterTypes = {byte[].class}` works too, as do your examples. The problem with your original code is trying to invoke getClass() _instance_ method on byte[] declaration.

Comment: (And that should probably be `Class<?>[]`.

Comment: `Integer[] x = {5}` works because `5` is autoboxed -- equivalent to `Integer.valueOf(5)`.